# display associative array containing product info brand by brand

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I developed a code in php where i can get the product info from database and save in an associative array and then i can display the according to my layout.Now problem for me is like when i pick products from database table,its in bulk means if i pick 1000 records of suppose 3 brands.I want to display them like one product for one brand then for second and then for third and repeating the case according to the number of products.Means i want to display the product list one by one brand name.
Following is my array in php which i m developing from PHP

```
$firstsql='SELECT * from xml where ('.implode('AND',$parts1).') ';

$firstsql3=mysql_query($firstsql);
$first=array();  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstsql3)) {

$first[]=$row;
}
```

And then i m iterating through this array using foreach loop only.if i have 300 records for first brand,200 for second and 500 for third.I want to iterate in such a way that first product should be from brand 1,second from brand2,third from brand3.

Please guide me on how to do this...

Code for array displaying format

```
<?php
foreach($countArray as $array)
{
?>

<div>
<a href="index23.php?name=<?php $array['IMAGEURL']?>"><img src="<?php echo $array['IMAGEURL']?>"/></a><br />
<h3><?php echo $array['BRAND']?></h3>
</div>
```

Tried the following code but didnt work properly

```
<?php
 $firstsql='SELECT * from xml ';
print($firstsql);
        $firstsql3=mysql_query($firstsql);
        $first=array();  
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstsql3)) {

            $first[]=$row;
        }

        $brand1 = array();
        $brand2 = array();
        $brand3 = array();

        //seperate the product by brand
        foreach($first as $v){
            if( $v['brand'] == 1 ){
                $brand1[] = $v;
            } else if( $v['brand'] == 2 ){
                $brand2[] = $v;
            } else if( $v['brand'] == 3 ){
                $brand3[] = $v;
            }
        }

        //count the number of product for each brand
        $brand1_c = count($brand1);
        $brand2_c = count($brand2);
        $brand3_c = count($brand3);
echo $brand1_c;
echo $brand2_c;
        //initialize the final product array
        $final = array();

        //get the highest count from each brand products
        $highest_number = max($brand1_c, $brand2_c, $brand3_c);

        //on basis of highest count go with for loop
        for( $i=1; $i<$highest_number; $i++  ){
            //check that array key exist or not brand1
            if (array_key_exists($i, $brand1)) {
                //add the product details in final product array
                $final[] = $brand1[$i];
            }

            //check that array key exist or not for brand2
            if (array_key_exists($i, $brand2)) {
                //add the product details in final product array
                $final[] = $brand2[$i];
            }                   

            //check that array key exist or not for brand3
            if (array_key_exists($i, $brand3)) {
                //add the product details in final product array
                $final[] = $brand3[$i];
            }
        }
        foreach($final as $array)
        {
        $i;
        ?>
        <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $array['IMAGEURL'] ?>"/>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i++;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: How do you want to handle when one of the arrays become empty?

Comment: @AmalMurali-One of the array means?There is only one array in post...

Comment: How is the array structured then? Can you show a `print_r()` output of the said array? (Format it with `<pre>` blocks to get a readable output.)

Comment: k.i have the normal div structure which i m using for it.i will paste that one.will that be fine?As i m new to PHP and not aware of print_r

Comment: Please check sir.if u want it with print_r as well,i will try to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS......

```
        $firstsql='SELECT * from xml where ('.implode('AND',$parts1).') ';

        $firstsql3=mysql_query($firstsql);
        $first=array();  
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstsql3)) {

            $first[]=$row;
        }

        $brand1 = array();
        $brand2 = array();
        $brand3 = array();

        //seperate the product by brand
        foreach($first as $v){
            if( $v['brand'] == 1 ){
                $brand1[] = $v;
            } else if( $v['brand'] == 2 ){
                $brand2[] = $v;
            } else if( $v['brand'] == 3 ){
                $brand3[] = $v;
            }
        }

        //count the number of product for each brand
        $brand1_c = count($brand1);
        $brand2_c = count($brand2);
        $brand3_c = count($brand3);

        //initialize the final product array
        $final = array();

        //get the highest count from each brand products
        $highest_number = max($brand1_c, $brand2_c, $brand3_c);

        //on basis of highest count go with for loop
        for( $i=1; $i<$highest_number; $i++  ){
            //check that array key exist or not brand1
            if (array_key_exists($i, $brand1)) {
                //add the product details in final product array
                $final[] = $brand1[$i];
            }

            //check that array key exist or not for brand2
            if (array_key_exists($i, $brand2)) {
                //add the product details in final product array
                $final[] = $brand2[$i];
            }                   

            //check that array key exist or not for brand3
            if (array_key_exists($i, $brand3)) {
                //add the product details in final product array
                $final[] = $brand3[$i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried with ur code friend but brand count is getting empty only,check my edited post please

Comment: have you checked $first variable contain data or not??

Comment: If $first has data then add the array in your post.

Comment: @data is there in $first variable.MY only doubt is here you have three brand arrays,brands are more than three in $first variable.Will this thing break the loop sir?There are about 20000 products in $first variable